# How to write a java program for this equation

Tags: java, math

Please take a look at this topic : 
[Can I calculate the average of these numbers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/340376/can-i-calculate-the-average-of-these-numbers?rq=1)
How can I write a program for this?
In the right answer, he just wrote the equation without the java program and he used for example newValue without intialise the newValue.
Here is the equation:

```java
int currentScore = (currentScore * currentCount + newValue) / currentCount;
```

Comment: The `currentScore` ought to be a `double`, not an `int`, and the divisor is `(currentCount + 1)`, since there is a new value.

Comment: I don't understand your question. Perhaps you should explain futher [what you have tried](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com).

Comment: my question is : if you look at the answer in the other post you will find a table and a formula.. He just answer by a formula but how can I put this formula in a java program??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please find broken steps as below:

```
   private float calculateNewScore(){
        float currentScore = 6.1123
        int currentCount = 12;
        float newValue = 4.5;
        int newCount = currentCount+1;

        float newScore = (currentScore * currentCount + newValue) / newCount ;

    }
```

If you are looking for sample program, it can be something like this:

```
 public class CalculateScore {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    float currentScore = 6.1123; //you can initialize with any desired value
    int currentCount = 12;//you can initialize with any desired value

    float newValue = 0;
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner( System.in );     

    do{
        System.out.println("Enter your new value. Enter 0 or negative to exit.");
        newValue = scanner.nextFloat();
        if(newValue>0){
            currentScore = (currentScore*currentCount+newValue)/(++currentCount);
            System.out.println("Your new score is "+currentScore);
        }else{
            System.out.println("Program is exiting");
        }

    }while(newValue >0);
   }
  }
```

Comment: but the newValue should not be fixed.. we should add a new value to a previous new value.. how can we do this? using a for loop?

Comment: Added a sample program to accept the `newValue` as input. Please check the added section in the answer.